# How to block the possibility of clicking the submit button in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to add a feature to my site. The user has to watch a short video. I would like to block the possibility of clicking the submit button before someone sees the video. Therefore, I would like it to remain inactive for the first 2 minutes.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<p> Please watch this 2-minutes video. </p>

<body>
  <center>
  <video width="744" height="576" controls>
    <source class="center" src="videos/nature.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</center>
<p></p>
<center>
<a href = "nextpage.html"><input style="height:50px; width: 100px; font-size:12pt;" type="submit" value="Next"></a></center>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *2 minutes* --- every body will leave your website 

Comment: 2 minutes of forced video is not short

Answer (score 0):

What you can so is to add event listener for when the video has ended, and then enable the button

```
document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('ended', videoEnded, false);
function videoEnded() {
    // Make the button clickable
}
```